# jQuery toggle - show only one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm an absolute beginner in javascript and jQuery, trying to learn.
I have some tables that are toggled with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('th').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('table').find('td').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

I would like to only show one table at a time, so that if you show the first table and then show another, the first one closes.
I would be very thankful for any guidance.
Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qHGDF/1/

Comment: can you show your divs/html??

Comment: Please show us a sample of your html code.

Comment: Sorry. Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/qHGDF/1/

Comment: Why using `th` instead of `div.datagrid`? Even the performance is better when going down the DOM tree not to mention it's more comfortable in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the ones that are open, one way to do this is to find all the td's that are not the one that needs to be shown and run `slideUp()`: http://jsfiddle.net/qHGDF/4/

```
$('th').click(function() {
    var thetd =  $(this).parents('table').find('td');
    $('table  td').not(thetd).slideUp("fast");
    $(thetd).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Great! Thanks to all of you. superUntitleds answer also allows closing of shown td. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  $('th').click(function() {
    $(".datagrid").children("table").find("td").slideUp();
    $(this).parents('table').find('td').slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always slide up all other td's

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('th').click(function() {
        $("td").slideUp("fast");
        $(this).parents('table').find('td').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to do that, you need to hide all the tds first

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        $('th').click(function() {
            $('table  td').hide(300);
            $(this).parents('table').find('td').slideToggle("fast");
        });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/uGhpH/)

Answer (score 0):

If you'll have too many entries on your tables, and for optimisation purposes on the rendering, *slide* the `<tbody>` element instead of `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5hDVS/

```
$(document).on('click','div.datagrid',function() {
     $('table td',this).slideToggle("fast");
     $('td',$(this).siblings('div.datagrid')).slideUp('fast');
});
```